# android's linux kernel scheduling mechanism vs harmony os's deterministic latency engine

Tags: linux, huawei, kernel

I was reading upon Harmony OS and found that android's Linux kernel scheduling mechanism has some limitations as mentioned here: https://harmonyosofficial.com/

*From Harmony OS website mentioned above:*

> Unlike Android which uses the Linux kernel’s scheduling mechanism,
> Harmony OS uses a “deterministic latency engine” that provides
> “precise resource scheduling with real-time load analysis and
> forecasting and app characteristics matching.” The result is a 25.7%
> and 55.6% improvement in response latency and latency fluctuation
> respectively. In addition, Huawei says the microkernel can make “IPC
> [Inter Process Communication] performance up to five times more
> efficient than existing systems.”

**Video tweet with explanation**

https://twitter.com/HuaweiMobile/status/1159725806320594945?s=19

I didn't understand these limitations properly. Can someone explain me in easy words along with the use cases?

How can this Harmony OS's new kernel benefit users/developers? Also, I'm a software engineer so I understand terms like scheduling etc. But I don't know how Linux Kernel does it vs Harmony's kernel

Comment: In this statements I don't see any limitation. It is just a statement that the kernel behaves more like a real-time kernel with lower latency. Hence multiple processes have to wait less time before they get CPU time to do whatever they want.

Comment: Why can't Linux kernel implement this if it's so good

Comment: Usually improvements are a trade-off. Looks like Huawei has optimized the system for IPC however this advantage most likely means that some other part of the scheduling system now faces some disadvantages.

Comment: What parts? What is IPC?